# Avoiding a repeated verb name in a train

Tags: j

Consider a dyadic verb `g`, defined in terms of a dyadic verb `f`:

```
g=. [ f&.|: f
```

Is it possible to rewrite `g` so that the `f` term appears only once, but the behavior is unchanged?

### UPDATE: Local Context

This question came up as part of my solution to [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145921/expand-an-array), which "expanding" a matrix in both directions like so:

**Original Matrix**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**Expanded Matrix**

```
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
```

My solution was to expand the matrix rows first using:

```
f=. ([ # ,:@{.@]) , ] , [ # ,:@{:@]
```

And then to apply that same solution under the transpose to expand the columns of the already row-expanded matrix:

```
3 ([ f&.|: f) m
```

And I noticed that it wasn't possible to write my solution with making the temporary verb `f`, or repeating its definition inline...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P9dWT8FQO1PPWMGYKzU5I18hF0Kpq3NxpQHlNKIVlBV0rByq9RxiNRV0FGKBGCZk5RALUWwMUpampldjpZCmqZD7/z8A)

Comment: Bob is right in the general case. If you give us more details and context on your specific case, there might be a local solution.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks.  I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing the context helps. You can also approach this using `(|:@f)^:(+: x) y`. A tacit (and golfed) solution would be `0&(|:{.,],{:)~+:`.

```
   (>: i. 3 3) (0&(|:{.,],{:)~+:) 2
1 1 1 2 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 3 3 3
4 4 4 5 6 6 6
7 7 7 8 9 9 9
7 7 7 8 9 9 9
7 7 7 8 9 9 9
```

Comment: that golfed solution is beautiful, but i can't figure out how you mapped the power `^:` solution down to it.  It parses [like this](https://paste2.org/MH0Pa9FW), which would mean that it's equivalent to `4 (0&(|:{.,],{:)) m`, but since 0 is already bonded as the left arg to the verb on its right, I don't see where the 4 comes into play or how it produces the final result.

Comment: @Jonah Let `m` be the matrix and `n` be the number of times that matrix is *expanded*. A breakdown for it is `m (0&(|:{.,],{:)~+:) n` to `m 0&(|:{.,],{:)~ (+: n)` to `(+: n) 0&(|:{.,],{:) m` to `(0&(|:{.,],{:))^:(+: n) m`

Comment: makes sense until the very last step: what rule is being applied there?

Comment: @Jonah It's another rule for bond `&` where a noun is bonded to a dyad, and then called dyadically. For example, `x m&f y` becomes `m&f^:x y`

Comment: ah, ok that makes sense i think genuinely didn't know about that one, or had at least thoroughly forgotten it.  great solution.  you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. The right tine is going to be the result of `x f y` and the left tine is `x` The middle tine will transpose and apply `f` to the arguments and then transpose the result back. If you take the right `f` out then there is not a way to have `x f y` and if the middle `f` is removed then you do not have `f` applied to the transpose.

My guess is that you are looking for a primitive that will accomplish the same result with only one mention of `f`, but I don't know of one.

Knowing the J community someone will prove me wrong!